# Object Oriented Programming in PHP

Tags: php, syntax

I've just started `OOP` in `PHP`, I could easily understand the use of `::` and `->`.

But when i see this, for instance,

```
$this->view->result
```

The use of the **two** `->` confuses me.

Can anyone help me out here ?

I'm tracing someone else's source code and would really like to get to the bottom of this.

Comment: How about starting by posting the code you're referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a look at some code:

```
$result = $this->view->result

// works exactly the same as

$view = $this->view;
$result = $view->result;
```

In other words `$this->view` is an object. Thus you can still retrieve objects attributes from it.

Comment: @AlexanderCogneau - This is not an exact copy of your answer. Your naming convention is different which makes it harder to understand. In addition I have an extra explanation.

Answer (score 2):

It's an object within an object. $this->view is an object, and that class has a property called result.

Answer (score 2):

when you use

```
$this->view
```

you get the view object which is a property of the current instance.

Doing

```
 $this->view->result
```

is the same as

```
$viewObject = $this->view;
$viewObject->result;
```

Comment: Thanks. The other explanations were a little confusing, I'm a novice so Sorry Guys and thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

As you already know `->` lets you access an attribute or a method. Obviously the attribute or method could contain another object as well. The second `->` will access an attribute or method of the inner object.

As an example:

```
class A {
    public $b = null;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->b = new B();
    }
    public function returnCinB() {
        return $this->b->c;
    }
}
class B {
    public $c = null;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->c = new C();
    }
}
class C { }

$a = new A();
var_dump($a->returnCinB()); // class C#3 (0) {
                            // }
```

Answer (score 0):

Imagine following classes:

```
class shop {
    ...
    public static function get_address() {
        return new address(123);
}

class address {
    ....
    public function get country() {
        return new country(456);
    }    
}

class country {
    ...
    get_continent() {
        return 'abc';
    }
}
```

When you call

```
shop::get_address()->get_country()->get_continent()
```

you will get 'abc'. You see, you can use even **stack and combine `->` and `::`** .

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->view->result
```

view is a variable in your class X and this variable is an object of another class Y where result is a variable of this class Y